# Web Performance and LoadTest in Azure Devops to ASP.Net Core Applications

Tags: azure, azure-devops, load-testing, web-performance

Am Working on Web Performance and LoadTest concept in Visual Studio and Azure Devops also. Still now, we worked on ASP.Net framework for our projects creations. Now, we have moved to ASP.NET core framework. So, here I need to do Web Performance and LoadTest to Web Application in ASP.NET core. Is there any way to do this test in this framework. If it is, please suggest me to "How to do it"

> And I wanted to test it in my Azure Devops under the **Hosted Linux
>   Preview** Agent.

Comment: Can you add testing script or some reference to what & how you are doing, without that error seems there is nothing to do in test script...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Pranav. Is there Web Performance and LoadTest support for .NET Core Applications

Comment: Web and Load tests send and receive http(s) to a web site. It does not matter how that site is constructed. Please [edit] you question to explain in more detail what you are doing, what is working and what is not working.

Comment: @AdrianHHH as you asked, I updated my question in above

Comment: Please read the [help] pages about how to write a good question here. As it stands this appears to be asking for a tutorial which is off-topic. The recently made edits provide no useful extra information. This is **YOUR** question, you need to put significant effort into writing something that we can understand and that has enough detail to provide an answer.